# AVR Bitwise Operations

Tags: arduino, avr, c, atmega

I am getting started learning more about AVR ATMEGA programming.
Reading an article about the inner workings of Arduinos, I am learning how the `shiftOut` method is structured. I am kind of familiar with bitwise operations so far, but I have an expression I do not understand yet:

```
void shiftOut(uint8_t dataPin, uint8_t clockPin, uint8_t bitOrder, uint8_t val)
{
    uint8_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)  {
        if (bitOrder == LSBFIRST) {
            PORTD |= !!(val & (HIGH << i)); 
        } else {
            PORTD |= !!(val & (HIGH << (7 - i)));           
        }   
        PORTB |= (HIGH << clockPin);
        PORTB ^= (HIGH << clockPin);
    }
}
```

The line `PORTD |= !!(val & (HIGH << i));` is not 100% clear to me. I understand that i set the i-th bit High on PORTD but what das the `!!` mean and `val&(HIGH <<i))`

I know this might sound basic, but can you please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, `!` is the logical negation operator: `!x` has the value 1 if `x` is falsy (i.e. zero), and the value 0 if `x` is truthy (i.e. non-zero). `!!x` has just two negations back-to-back, which gives the same logical truth value as `x` itself, *but* it collapses all true values to `1`. (It's worth remembering that e.g. `2`, `0x1000`, and `-123` are all true in C.)

```
(val & (HIGH << i))
```

This is just `HIGH` shifted left by `i` bits, and that value *anded* with `val`. i.e. if `HIGH` is `1`, it picks the `i`th bit of `val` (counting from zero).

So, e.g. if `i` is 3, `(val & (1 << i))` might be `0x08`, and the following `!!` would collapse that to `1`.